# Как я могу забросить в бд на MYSQL URL адрес картинки?

Tags: javascript, mysql, url

Я хочу загружать картинки через input type file и хранить их в бд. Для работы с бд я использую ORM sequalize. Front-end на React, а Backend на Express. Прежде, чем отправить картинку на бек я её обрабатываю в FileReader.

```js
const changeFileHandler = (e) => {
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend = (evt) => {
            setCurrentPhoto(evt.target.result);
            console.log(evt.target.result);
          };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        
    }
```

На выходе я получаю очень длинную строку URL, а при отправки её на сервер выдаётся ошибка POST http://localhost:3000/ 413 (Payload Too Large). Я пробовал в качестве типа данных TEXT и VARCHAR, но не помогло. Как это исправить и может быть есть способ по проще?

Comment: 413 ошибку выдает скорее всего не ваш скрипт, а web сервер. не знаю что там у вас стоит apache, nginx или еще что то, но допустимые размеры передаваемых данных для начала надо посмотреть в их конфигах

Comment: ну и надо понимать что все таки это не совсем url, а сама картинка в base64 кодировке, т.е. эта длинная строка на 1/3 больше по рамеру чаем сам файл картинки и может занимать многие мегабайты. не стоит такое хранить в базе данных. стоит картинки отдельно сохранять на диск в виде файлов и потом оперировать url на эти файлы

Comment: Понятно, спасибо. По поводу сервера - у меня просто сервер, написанный на express, т.е. я веб сервера не скачивал. По поводу сохранять картинки на диск - я пробовал этот вариант. Проблема в том, что когда загружаешь картинку через input file, он даёт не полный путь к картинки, а её fakepath/ Например C://fakepath/3.jpg. Как я вычитал - это сделано для безопасности серверов, чтобы не загружали абы что

Comment: Собирайте путь для отправки в БД таким образом: полный адрес корневого каталога сайта + путь к папке для загрузки файлов, который указываете в серверном коде загрузки файлов на сервер + имя загружаемого файла. На пример **http://mysite.com/images/3.jpg** Проблем быть не должно.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за совет